# Migrate from sync Flask to async Flask

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, async-await

Currently, I have a Flask backend with synchronous routes, and I'm planning to migrate to an asynchronous implementation.
I'm wondering how long this process will take and how challenging it will be to convert all of my 25 routes to async in Flask. From what I've read, it seems that I need to:

1. Replace the synchronous route functions with asynchronous route functions.
2. Replace the synchronous request handlers with asynchronous request handlers.
3. Replace the synchronous database calls with asynchronous database calls.

Do I need to take any other steps during this migration?
Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

in general you are right, steps that you mentioned are definitely the most important one for this migration. Additionally you should consider moving every I/O operation as well as API calls and message queueing  to the asynchronous model.